# I cant set or add flags and expunge the mails permanentley using their UIDs in imap-node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, imap

```
let emailUid = [28276,28277,28278,28275];

    await imap.openBox("[Gmail]/All Mail", false, async function (err, box) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return;
      }
      console.log("box opened",box.name);

      //  new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
                // Mark the email as deleted
                let flags= ['\\Deleted']
                imap.setFlags(emailUid, flags, async function (err) {
                  if (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    //reject(err)
                  } else {
                    console.log('Flags added to the emails:', emailUid);
                    // resolve()
                    imap.expunge();
                  }
                });
              // })
    });
    await new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
     imap.expunge(function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log('Expunge operation completed successfully.');
        resolve()
      }
    })
    });
```

connection to IMAP is successful .then the console logs in imap.expunge is printed first then the log in imap.setflags is printed. finally , flags are not set to the mail and expunge operation is not completed when seen in the gmail
I tried running the above code , but the output is:

```
{connected to imap
box opened [Gmail]/All Mail
Expunge operation completed successfully.
Flags added to the emails: [ 28276, 28277, 28278, 28275 ]
connection ended}
```

I expected the emails with UIDs to get deleted permanently but it did nothing and the email remains untouched.

Comment: Please provide input _and_ output in text, not as images.

Comment: Also, gmail doesn't quite follow the protocol.  To fully delete an item you need to move it into the (language specific) Trash folder.

Comment: yes, but if it is moved to trash then you click empty trash now , will add or set flag and expunge it maybe!

Comment: Once you'ved it into the Trash, you can switch to the Trash folder than do \Deleted/Expunge.